# How many plural should I use here?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, plural-forms, singular-vs-plural

I am writing a thesis and the title goes like this:

> "Interaction of Proteins with Small Molecules and Peptides"

I studied the interactions of various different proteins with various different small molecules and peptides. For example I studied the interactions of protein A with small molecule A and small molecule B; and then interactions of protein B with peptide A and small molecule C and so on. Therefore, in the title proteins mean protein in general and small molecules indicate small molecule in general.

So, will it be better if I write:

> "Interactions of Protein with Small Molecule and Peptide"

Or should I use all plural:

> "Interactions of Proteins with Small Molecules and Peptides"

Does the above mentioned fragment sounds good as a title? Should I use something like "Studies on" on the beginning? Can "Studies on" be implicit?

Comment: I can't see a case where any of these is singular or a group, so I would use plurals. Is there a reason you considered singular nouns?

Comment: @user3169 I was most worried about the first word. I thought if I use "Interactions", I should write it like interactions of this and that (e.g. Interactions of man and his environment). Whereas if I use interaction, I should write Interaction of this with that (e.g. Interaction of man with his environment). I googled those examples. I'm not sure if those are correct though. Again, in both the examples they used man, not men. And by protein I want to mean any protein, not confined to the particular group of proteins I studied. Because main subject of my study is how they interact.

Comment: I think this is going to be a question of writing style, esp. in a title. You might ask this on [***Writers SE***](http://writers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Use the all plural title you first wrote. However, changing it to "The Interaction of Proteins with Small Molecules and Peptides" makes it sound a bit better depending on your preference.

Comment: I disagree with adding "The", because that seems to imply there is only one interaction being studied.

Answer (score 0):

Your example sounds perfect to me for the following reasons:

1. it copies the style other authors have used for your context,
2. it is accurate; using singulars instead of plurals would change the
   meaning (to inaccurate)
3. the use of *protein* (singular) suggests that the type of protein does not
   matter;  I'm assuming this is *not* what you mean, but if it is then
   use it.